# pyspark filter a column by regular expression?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i would like to filter a column in my pyspark dataframe using regular expression.
I want to do something like this but using regular expression:

```
newdf = df.filter("only return rows with 8 to 10 characters in column called category")
```

This is my regular expression:

```
regex_string = "(\d{8}$|\d{9}$|\d{10}$)"
```

column category is of string type in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **`length()`** function in spark.

**Example:**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('abcdefghij',),('abcdefghi',),('abcdefgh',),('abcdefghijk',)],['str_col'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.filter((length(col("str_col")) >= 8) & (length(col("str_col")) <= 10)).show()
#+----------+
#|   str_col|
#+----------+
#|abcdefghij|
#| abcdefghi|
#|  abcdefgh|
#+----------+
```

**Using Regex `.rlike` function:**

```
df.filter(col("str_col").rlike("^\w{8,10}$")).show()
#+----------+
#|   str_col|
#+----------+
#|abcdefghij|
#| abcdefghi|
#|  abcdefgh|
#+----------+
```